# SQL Not Like Statement not working in conditional statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following conditional statement:

```
where l_view.TitleT LIKE '%ed%Build%' and l_view.TitleT NOT LIKE '%ed%Build%none%'
```

As you can see I want to see the records that have `%ed%Build%` in their title but not `%ed%Build%none%`. For example, if the title has `"ed build(none)"`, or `"ed build(none needed)"` that record should not be listed in my results. However, I can still see these results! do you guys have any clue why this is happening?

Thanks,

Comment: That `WHERE` [works for me](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=74fbcee052f24120fe46581daa67fe0a). Can you provide us with an example that replicates this issue?

Comment: Please provide sample data to illustrate your point.

Comment: Which collation the `TitleT` column has? Is it case-sensitive, by any chance?

Comment: @RogerWolf, it is not case sensitive. I am preparing some sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried and found OK with the sample data:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE
(
    Id INT,
    Name VARCHAR(100),
    Title VARCHAR(300)
)

INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Name, Title) VALUES(1,'1','ed build(none)')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Name, Title) VALUES(2,'2','ed 11 build 22')
INSERT INTO @tbl(Id, Name, Title) VALUES(3,'3','ed build(none needed)')

SELECT * FROM @tbl 
WHERE Title LIKE '%ed%Build%' and Title NOT LIKE '%ed%Build%none%'
```

Result:

[image]

Let me know some more sample data so that We can see the issue: